# Как изменить ссылку на сборку?

Tags: c#

Пишу бота для дискорда. Взял либу Discord.Net. 
У меня win7, в которой .Net-овские сокеты не поддерживаются ( Что-то такое пишет при попытке запуска )

Пробую использовать сторонний провайдер сокетов, а именно WebSocket4Net. 
При загрузке этой либы из nuget вместе с дискордом, возникает ошибка:
Как я понял, дискорд не смог найти в WebSocket4Net конструктор с нужной сигнатурой.

Окей. Я настырный. Скачал исходник WebSocket4Net и действительно, у конструктора добавлен обязательный параметр размераБуфера. Сделал его не обязательным, указав по стандарту 4048бит.

Собрал и попробовал подменить библиотеку на свою. Но Поймал ошибку:

Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "WebSocket4Net, Version=0.15.2.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb4e154b696bf72a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Как избавляются от этой гадости?)

Comment: Ну семёрка не XP, но вы не хотите "настырно" поменять свою платформу разработки на что-то более современное? Windows 7 перестала получать основную поддержку 13 января 2015 г., а в 2020 году прекратится и расширенная поддержка.

Comment: почитал, улыбнулся, второй раз прочитал (думал упустил что-то) нет не упустил, родился вопрос - какая разница между wn7 - winserver 2008 (r2) win 8.1, winserver 2012  с последим сервис паком 4.  Графический интерфейс?  думаю просто кривая система стоит. А недостающие файлы датированы 2010 годом.

Comment: Возможно я что-то путаю, но PublicKeyToken используется в том случае, если .dll сконфигурирована с использованием строгого имени, т.е она должна быть подписанной. В таком случае получается, манифест оригинальной сборки не совпадает с тем, что было получено в результате изменений.

Comment: _подменить библиотеку на свою_  - Как подменяли?

Comment: @UserName Да собвственно, просто удалил ссылку на родную библиотеку и указал ссылку на свою.

Comment: Зависимости к данной библиотеки, которые подтягиваются через NuGet есть?

Comment: Сносить привычную мне 7ку ради поддержки .Net-овского сокет клиента? 
Оно может и верно в перспективе. Но это первая подобная проблема.

Comment: @UserName Она вроде ничего не тянет с нугета. Она же мелкая либа. Просто сокет-клиент.

Comment: не нужно сносить 7-ку, нужно установить недостающие компоненты

Comment: @DigitalCore, приму к сведению. Но все же хотелось бы научиться решать подобные проблемы. А не надеяться на виндоус.

Comment: сделайте сборку без строго имени , без подписи, найдите зависимости.

Comment: @DigitalCore Сделал сборку без подписи. Нашел зависимость от пакета: SuperSocket.ClientEngine. Эту библиотеку я не трогал. пробовал как ту что подгружается вместе с Discord.Net так и ту, что построилась вместе с моей измененной библиотекой.

Ошибка все та же:

Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "WebSocket4Net, Version=0.15.2.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb4e154b696bf72a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Discord.Net/ Здесь же расписаны зависимости.